# How to get the radio button inside a label, which is inside a div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Suppose I have the following HTML.

```
<div id="bookmarksList">
  <label class="container">
    <input type="radio" name="bookmark" id="b1"
        onclick="onClicked(this);" checked="checked">
    <span class="radioTitle">2014</span>
  </label>
  <label class="container">
    <input type="radio" name="bookmark" id="b2"
        onclick="onClicked(this);" checked="checked">
    <span class="radioTitle">2015</span>
  </label> //So on upto 10
</div>
```

in onClicked() function, I want to change the color of the checked checkbox's label to red.

I want to do this using jQuery's find() method, but it is giving `undefined`

```
$("#bookmarksList").find("input[type=radio]").each(() => {
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

OR

```
$("#bookmarksList").find("label > input[type=radio]").each(() => {
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

How should I do it? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with a normal function, instead of an arrow function here, then it should work.
This worked for me:

```
$("#bookmarksList").find("input[type=radio]").each(function() {
        console.log(this.id);
});
```

But anyway, I would suggest to also do a class for your inputs you want to fetch via jQuery, then you can just get it normal via `$('yourClass').each(function() {....}` or if you only want to get your elements w/ this class inside your `#bookmarksList` div:
`$('#bookmarkslist .yourClass').each(function() {....}`

Comment: Can also access the current element from the `each` callback arguments

Answer (score 1):

Does it work right? I mean there no need JS.

```js
function onClicked(id) {
  console.log(id)
}
```

```css
input:checked+label {
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<div id="bookmarksList">
  <input type="radio" name="bookmark" id="b1"
      onclick="onClicked(this.id)" checked>
  <label for "b1">
    <span class="radioTitle">2014</span>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" name="bookmark" id="b2"
      onclick="onClicked(this.id)">
  <label for "b1">
    <span class="radioTitle">2015</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: What does *"no need JS"* mean?

Comment: @charlietfl, in this case, I show how to catch id with JS, but TS first of all needed to change the checked radio, what I do without JS.

Comment: That makes even less sense

Comment: @charlietfl i don't understand what you mean. He wants to customize checked, I write hot do this without JS.

Comment: Using `onClick` is still using JS. I think you mean *without using jQuery*

Comment: @charlietfl Please check what do `onClick` in my code -> nothing. In my answer I show: 1) how that make without js, 2) why his js not working.  You can delete JS in my answer, and that still works.

Comment: Ok fine but you show a JS function yet say no JS needed....that is confusing and unclear

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ids of the inputs like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bookmarksList input[type=radio]").each(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="bookmarksList">
  <label class="container">
    <input type="radio" name="bookmark" id="b1" onclick="onClicked(this);" checked="checked">
    <span class="radioTitle">2014</span>
  </label>
  
  <label class="container">
    <input type="radio" name="bookmark" id="b2" onclick="onClicked(this);" checked="checked">
    <span class="radioTitle">2015</span>
  </label>
</div>
```